# TypeError: Unknown encoding: 1 (mongoose@4.7.5)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, bson, mongoose-schema

I am using below code but its show..below picture type data i want document of job.. how to do this please help me. i want to show response in local variable. I am using nodejs moongoose schema and promises

```
export function getresult(req, res) {
    Job.findById(req.params.id)
    .exec()
    .then(GetdifferenceResult(res))
    .catch(errorhand(res));
}

function GetdifferenceResult(response, statusCode) {
    console.log('job', response);
    var GetData = response;
}
```

Output:

[image]

### Update:

Code issue fixed but it shows the error now:

> TypeError: Unknown encoding: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just don't pass any parameter in `GetdifferenceResult`:

```
Job.findById(req.params.id)
.exec()
.then(function (_job) {
    console.log('job', _job);
    res.send(_job); //send response to client
})
.catch(errorhand(res));
```

---

### **Update:**

It is the problem with [`npm bson 1.0.2`](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/4864).

**Solution:** update bson to version 1.0.3:

```
npm install bson@1.0.3
```

Comment: can you please chat

Comment: bhai bat krni hai apse

Comment: TypeError: Unknown encoding: 1

Comment: @AddiKhan I've edited and added a promise handler instead of passing a reference to a function.

Comment: when i enter this console.log(_job.name); its show name of job..but i want full document... console.log(_job); its how error

Comment: How can you get the `name` if you're getting error?? Also which version of `bson` are you using?

Comment: puri job ka array return krne me error de rha hai..agar specific column chahiya wo de rha hai.. ;(

Comment: mongoose@>=4.5.8 <5.0.0",
   "mongoose@4.7.5",  "
  "_nodeVersion": "6.9.0",

Comment: Go into the `mongodb` node_module folder run this command `npm install bson@1.0.3` to update your `bson npm` to latest version. [In reference to this bug](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/4864). Please try to communicate in english it could help other's having same problem in future.